# How to Overlock on 775i945GZ?

Tags: overclocking

I have no clue how to overclock on this motherboard.( http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=775I945GZ )

[image]

[image]

[image]

At Over clock mode I can select PCIe Sync and Async at it makes my CPU Frequency button blue, as I could select it and change it. But I can't. What should I look for ? Should I change the BIOS ?

LE: I got the BUS Frequency at 215 and now I have 1,72 GHz. The temperature of the cores are around 61-63. Is this good ? I want to increase it. At what temperature should I stop ?

Comment: Don't apologise for asking questions, "niche" questions like these are good - means somebody else wanting to know can more easily find out, too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the PCIe to Async
2. Set the Overclock Mode to Manual
3. Turn up the CPU Frequency by 5-10 Hz
4. Boot up your OS and run a stress test
5. If it crashes, turn down the frequency 2-5 Hz and go to 4.
6. If it passes, go to 3.
7. Once you find the maximum turn it down 1-2 Hz for a little extra stability.

I recommend [prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) as the stress testing application.

Also, make sure the temperature alarm is on while overclocking. You should be able to set the BIOS to automatically turn off the computer when a certain temperature is reached. 70-80 degrees Celsius is typical.

Comment: At OverClock Mode I only have: Auto, PCIe Sync and PCIe Async. Not any manual mode.

Comment: Then pick Async, otherwise the PCIe bus will also get overclocked and could cause stability problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you increase the multiplier or the bus frequency, which will increase your cpu frequency along with your memory frequency.  This is why overclocking is much more than just a cpu increase and all parts of the computer come into play.  You are limited by whatever your weakest component is and its "limit".  You may find a setting that works, but you might start seeing weird errors or lockups after a few minutes.  Make sure to watch your temperatures also so you do not ruin anything.  And like people mentioned in all those related questions, increment slowly.

Comment: The multiplier on pretty much all CPUs except for the "Extreme" editions are locked and cannot be changed in BIOS.

Comment: Yah, I know, I just mentioned it cause if you move any of those values, the others will change with it.  Ben is correct though.  The only processors that can be independently increased are the "extreme" series of processors (intel) or the "black editions" (AMD).